# RSA 4096 bit key benchmark

Tags: rsa, performance

How can I benchmark RSA operations on my computer? I want to know about 4096-bit long keys on general computers. How many encryptions and decryptions are possible per second? All benchmarks I found only show 1024- and 2048-bit keys.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, the private key operation will be 8 times and the public key operation 4 times as expensive than what RSA 2048 needs.

Comment: But if you want high performance and high security, why RSA? You could use a ~256 bit (or if paranoid ~512 bit) elliptic curve. That's pretty fast and offers a security level of 128 bit (or 256 bit for a 512 bit curve).

Comment: @CodesInChaos what is elliptic curve relation to RSA?

Comment: ECDH is a protocol not a key like RSA to distribute publicly ..

Comment: Implementing asymmetric encryption on top of ECDH is trivial. ECDH can do almost everything RSA encryption can do. Just like with RSA you have a key-pair, which can be long term, and can be used for encryption.

Comment: That might help you : [Benchmark](http://bench.cr.yp.to/primitives-encrypt.html)

Comment: @CodesInChaos ok if you have link of implementation source code please share. so ECDH make smaller and faster keys which have more security even than largest RSA keys, right ?

Comment: I guess it's just vocabulary here but rather than ECDH an elliptic curve alternative for mary would be [ECIES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_Encryption_Scheme) which uses ECDH as a key establishment scheme

Comment: @CodesInChaos ECC is much harder to grasp and much less supported in the wild. Side channel attacks on ECC are still not well researched. There are also quite a few pitfalls (e.g. regarding the signing and the random number generator). I'm pretty much in favor of it for the long term. Currently I would recommend to stick to the NIST curves, especially the named P-256 curve. For beginners, I would recommend RSA, if you want to grasp what's going on.

Comment: @owlstead Personally I like Curve25519/Ed25519 a lot. Quite fast, no timing attacks, compressed points(no validation required) and no random numbers for signing. It's no NIST standard, but that doesn't matter for my personal projects.

Comment: @CodesInChaos It's mostly brainpool curves that do it for me. The generation process is well described, and the parameters are nicely bit-aligned, which makes it much easier to port to any platform, except Microsoft CNG of course. Maybe not as speedy, but many other advantages.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A "general computer" simply doesn't exist, test for yourself with this command:

```
openssl speed rsa
```

As an example here is the output on a Mac Pro 2007 with[Intel Xeon 5130](http://ark.intel.com/products/27216/Intel-Xeon-Processor-5130-4M-Cache-2_00-GHz-1333-MHz-FSB):

```
Doing 512 bit private rsa's for 10s: 67450 512 bit private RSA's in 9.95s
Doing 512 bit public rsa's for 10s: 961891 512 bit public RSA's in 9.94s
Doing 1024 bit private rsa's for 10s: 19914 1024 bit private RSA's in 9.93s
Doing 1024 bit public rsa's for 10s: 343029 1024 bit public RSA's in 9.98s
Doing 2048 bit private rsa's for 10s: 3101 2048 bit private RSA's in 10.00s
Doing 2048 bit public rsa's for 10s: 100363 2048 bit public RSA's in 10.00s
Doing 4096 bit private rsa's for 10s: 430 4096 bit private RSA's in 9.95s
Doing 4096 bit public rsa's for 10s: 27080 4096 bit public RSA's in 9.93s
OpenSSL 1.0.1 14 Mar 2012
built on: Tue Aug 21 05:18:48 UTC 2012
options:bn(64,64) rc4(16x,int) des(idx,cisc,16,int) aes(partial) blowfish(idx) 
compiler: cc -fPIC -DOPENSSL_PIC -DZLIB -DOPENSSL_THREADS -D_REENTRANT -DDSO_DLFCN -DHAVE_DLFCN_H -m64 -DL_ENDIAN -DTERMIO -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Wformat-security -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wa,--noexecstack -Wall -DOPENSSL_NO_TLS1_2_CLIENT -DOPENSSL_MAX_TLS1_2_CIPHER_LENGTH=50 -DMD32_REG_T=int -DOPENSSL_IA32_SSE2 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT5 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_GF2m -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DMD5_ASM -DAES_ASM -DVPAES_ASM -DBSAES_ASM -DWHIRLPOOL_ASM -DGHASH_ASM
                  sign    verify    sign/s verify/s
rsa  512 bits 0.000148s 0.000010s   6778.9  96769.7
rsa 1024 bits 0.000499s 0.000029s   2005.4  34371.6
rsa 2048 bits 0.003225s 0.000100s    310.1  10036.3
rsa 4096 bits 0.023140s 0.000367s     43.2   2727.1
```

And here is the same command on a slightly more up-to-date mobile (aka laptop) CPU ([Intel i5 2540M](http://ark.intel.com/products/50072/Intel-Core-i5-2540M-Processor-3M-Cache-up-to-3_30-GHz))

```
Doing 512 bit private rsa's for 10s: 178265 512 bit private RSA's in 10.00s
Doing 512 bit public rsa's for 10s: 2244112 512 bit public RSA's in 10.01s
Doing 1024 bit private rsa's for 10s: 52008 1024 bit private RSA's in 10.00s
Doing 1024 bit public rsa's for 10s: 792898 1024 bit public RSA's in 10.01s
Doing 2048 bit private rsa's for 10s: 7216 2048 bit private RSA's in 10.00s
Doing 2048 bit public rsa's for 10s: 232383 2048 bit public RSA's in 10.01s
Doing 4096 bit private rsa's for 10s: 1012 4096 bit private RSA's in 10.01s
Doing 4096 bit public rsa's for 10s: 62854 4096 bit public RSA's in 10.01s
OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013
built on: Mon Jul 15 12:44:45 UTC 2013
options:bn(64,64) rc4(16x,int) des(idx,cisc,16,int) aes(partial) blowfish(idx) 
compiler: cc -fPIC -DOPENSSL_PIC -DZLIB -DOPENSSL_THREADS -D_REENTRANT -DDSO_DLFCN -DHAVE_DLFCN_H -m64 -DL_ENDIAN -DTERMIO -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wa,--noexecstack -Wall -DOPENSSL_NO_TLS1_2_CLIENT -DOPENSSL_MAX_TLS1_2_CIPHER_LENGTH=50 -DMD32_REG_T=int -DOPENSSL_IA32_SSE2 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT5 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_GF2m -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DMD5_ASM -DAES_ASM -DVPAES_ASM -DBSAES_ASM -DWHIRLPOOL_ASM -DGHASH_ASM
                  sign    verify    sign/s verify/s
rsa  512 bits 0.000056s 0.000004s  17826.5 224187.0
rsa 1024 bits 0.000192s 0.000013s   5200.8  79210.6
rsa 2048 bits 0.001386s 0.000043s    721.6  23215.1
rsa 4096 bits 0.009891s 0.000159s    101.1   6279.1
```

Comment: Mine gets all the way up to 126 RSA private key ops :)